# Retopology: Applying glove to hand

Tags: modeling

I have a pair of gloves and a character where the gloves are from another character. 
The gloves do not fit the character.
What can I do to make the gloves fit the character's hands.
I've thought of shrinkwrap, but I am not sure how to group the vertex to get it fit properly.